# Conflicting types present in two Silverlight dlls

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, controls

Scenario:

I have created two custom controls in Silverlight, MyCustomControl1 and MyCustomControl2. Both the controls have a namespace called Control.Generic. Control.Generic has an enum type called PageOrientation. I want to use both the controls (MyCustomControl1 and MyCustomControl2) together in my project. I have added references to these two controls in my project. Now, how can I include the namespace Control.Generic for both the controls in my class file? Currently I have specified it as shown below:

```
using Control.Generic;
```

But the problem is when I am using the PageOrientation enum, I am getting the following exception.

The type 'Control.Generic.PageOrientation' exists in both 'MyCustomControl1.dll' and 'MyCustomControl2.dll'.

How can I resolve this conflict?

Comment: Don't know if it will work for you but since Global qualifier won't work here, maybe you can create a second class and use using statement there and make that class static and return object of type of second user control from that class to first class. Kinda complicated.

Answer (score 2):

It is common to want to share classes/enums etc between your user controls. You should avoid having the exact same fully-qualified name in any two libraries.

What you want to do is have a common library, referenced by both user control libraries, containing any common elements you may want to reuse.

e.g.

`Controls.Generic.dll` contains `Control.Generic.PageOrientation`
and `MyCustomControl1.dll` and `MyCustomControl1.dll` simply reference `Controls.Generic.dll`.

As a rule your libraries and namespaces within them should match. If they don't you are probably trying to do something you shouldn't :)

Basically start treating your own libraries like third-party controls and use naming standards like they do (company.subarea.featureset etc). It will save you a lot of trouble in the long run.